# Namespace.exe does not contains a static Main Method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a console application for implementing a normal Stack operation. However when I am trying to call the Push and Pop method through the Main Method. I am getting the following error. Then I have created a separate class "STACK" and paste the entire code within that class. Now even when I am trying to create the instance of class STACK and then referring the Push and Pop methods from the main method, still I am getting the error.

StackImplementation.exe does not contains a static Main Method suitable for an entry point

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

 namespace StackImplementation
 {

  class stack
  {
      int[] a=new int[5];
      int top = -1;

    public void push(int value)
    {
        if (top == 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The List is Full");
        }
        else
        top = top + 1;
        a[top] = value;
    }

    public void pop()
    {
        if (top == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The List is Empty");
        }

        else
            top = top - 1;   
    }

    public void display()
    {
        int i;

        if (top == -1)
            Console.WriteLine("Nothing to Display");
        else    
        for (i = 1; i < top; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The List is {0}",a[i]);
        }
     }
  }

    class Program
    {
        static int main()
        {
            stack stc = new stack();
            int choice, value;
            do
            {

                Console.WriteLine("/n 1.Push");
                Console.WriteLine("/n 2.Pop");
                Console.WriteLine("/n 3.Display");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Choice");
                choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (choice == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the value to be inserted");
                    value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    stc.push(value);
                }

                if (choice == 2)
                {
                    stc.pop();
                }

                if (choice == 3)
                {
                    stc.display();
                }
            } while (choice != 0);
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As lazyberezovsky answered any program needs a static Main method. Since C# is case-sensitive your main method is just not correctly named. Name it 'Main'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C# is case-sensitive.

Rename `main` to `Main` so that the compiler sees the proper entry-point.

Answer (score 0):

Any C# program should have static method `Main` where execution starts. See [Main () and Other Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) article:

> Every C# application must contain a single Main method specifying
>   where program execution is to begin. **In C#, Main is capitalized**, while
>   Java uses lowercase main.

So, just make your `main` method name Pascal case (capitalized). Actually this naming convention is applied to type names and all other methods in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Program Main to:

```
static int Main()
```

Notice the change in case, C# is case sensitive.

Comment: Not needed to make it `public`.